# Why I can duplicate a string by this way but not this way?

Tags: string, loops, unary-operator

This code works fine to me and I can understand it:

```
char * strduplica(char *s)
{
    int i, len = strlen(s);

    for (i=0; i<len; i++)
        s[i+len] = s[i];

    s[i+len] = '\0';

    return s;
}

main()
{
    char s[20]="Ana";
    puts(strduplica(s));
}
```

Before, I tried this and I got a "Segmentation Fault". Why?:

```
for (i=0; i<len; i++)
    s[len++] = s[i];

s[len] = '\0';
```

The output should be: "AnaAna".

Answer (score 1):

Because you were incrementing `len` which is used in the `for` termination condition:

```
for (i=0; i<len; i++)
```

In every iteration both `i` and `len` are incremented. Thus, `i` always stays less than `len`, and you get an infinite loop.

Eventually, the loop writes a value beyond the allocated area which results in the segmentation fault.

Comment: What a mess! I see now. Thank you, Alex.